# How to get text, name attribute and other non-standard attributes from selected option?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `select` html-tag with several `options`.

Here is an example:

```
<select id="mySelect1" size="4" style="width:100px;">
    <option value="AUS" 
            name="Australia" 
            city="Canberra"
            >Australia</option>

    <option selected value="CAN" 
                     name="North America" 
                     city="Ottawa"
                     >Canada</option>

    <option value="GRC" 
            name="Europe" 
            city="Athens"
            >Greece</option>

    <option value="JPN" 
            name="Asia" 
            city="Tokyo"
            >Japan</option>
</select>
```

I know how to **`alert`** the `value` of the selected option:

```
alert(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].value);
```

But when I try to **`alert`** the `city` or even the `name` of the selected option I fail, with almost the same code:

```
alert(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].city);
alert(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].name);
```

Is it possible to get **any `attribute`** and the **`text`** from the selected `option` in pure javascript?

Comment: In addition to the answer below you can have a look at **querySelectorAll**, which might help you to get any attribute. One of the examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67766125/5410914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is possible.

First of all, your code does not work with `city` and `name` attributes of the **`option`** tag because [HTML option Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) has **neither `name`, nor `city` attribute**, they are not standard!

If you ever wish, you can use a standard **`label`** attribute instead of `name`, so the similar minimalist code would work:

```
//Get label attribute:
alert(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].label);
```

But in any way, apart from `name`, you've got `city`. So you need to use `attributes` for getting such non-standard attributes. Therefore, here is the code that works with the selected option, based on your example:

```js
document.write('<br>');

//Get innerText:
document.write(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].innerText + '<br>');

//Get value attribute:
document.write(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].value + '<br>');

//Get name attribute:
document.write(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].attributes.name.value + '<br>');

//Get city attribute:
document.write(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].attributes.city.value + '<br>');
```

```html
<select id="mySelect1" size="4" style="width:100px;">
    <option value="AUS" 
            name="Australia" 
            city="Canberra"
            >Australia</option>

    <option selected value="CAN" 
                     name="North America" 
                     city="Ottawa"
                     >Canada</option>

    <option value="GRC" 
            name="Europe" 
            city="Athens"
            >Greece</option>

    <option value="JPN" 
            name="Asia" 
            city="Tokyo"
            >Japan</option>
</select>
```

So this is how it works.

For you to understand more, all attributes can be retrieved from `attributes`. That means that you can (but of course **do not need to!**) use `attributes` with standard attributes, like this:

```
alert(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].attributes.value.value);
alert(mySelect1.options[mySelect1.options.selectedIndex].attributes.label.value);
```